# Предупреждение в функции qsort

Tags: c

Компилятор выдает предупреждение: passing argument 4 of 'qsort' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

и замечание: `expected 'int (*)(const void *, const void *)' but argument is of type 'int (*)(Athlet *, Athlet *) {aka int (*)(struct _Athlet *, struct _Athlet *)}'`

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Athlet
{
    double m;
    double s;
} Athlet;

Athlet read_athlet()
{
    Athlet at;
    scanf("%lf %lf", &at.m, &at.s);
    return at;
}

int cmp_by_s(Athlet *a1, Athlet *a2)
{
    return a1->s - a2->s;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0, max = 1, tmp = 0, i = 0;
    Athlet *A = NULL;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    A = (Athlet *)malloc(n*sizeof(Athlet));
    if (NULL == A)
        exit(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = read_athlet();

    qsort(A, n, sizeof(Athlet), cmp_by_s);
        tmp = A[0].m;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i ++)
    {
        if (A[i].s >= tmp)
        {
            max++;
            tmp += A[i].m;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", max);
    return 0;

}
```

(Это решение задачи: написать программу, которая находит «башню» из атлетов максимальной высоты. Атлеты характеризуются двумя параметрами – массой и силой. Сила равна максимальной массе, которую атлет может держать на плечах. Известно, что если атлет тяжелее, то он точно сильнее. Входом является число атлетов n и n пар (масса, сила))

Answer (score 1):

Это не должно компилироваться. Если вы получаете предупреждение, а не ошибку, значит настройки компилятора недостаточно строгие.

`qsort` принимает функцию вида `int foo(const void *a, const void *b)`. Параметры должны быть именно `const void *`.

`int cmp_by_s(Athlet *a1, Athlet *a2) {...}` нужно заменить на:

```
int cmp_by_s(const void *a1_ptr, const void *a2_ptr)
{
    const Athlet *a1 = (const Athlet *)a1_ptr;
    const Athlet *a2 = (const Athlet *)a2_ptr;
    return a1->s - a2->s;
}
```